# Need to show submenu to the right of it's parent item

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I have an unordered list like this:

```
<ul>
 <li>Parent-1
  <ul>
    <li>Child-1</li>
    <li>Child-2</li>
    <li>Child-3</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Parent-2
  <ul>
    <li>Child-4</li>
    <li>Child-5</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Parent-3
  <ul>
    <li>Child-6</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

And the result needs to display inline like this:

**Parent-1** | Child-1 | Child-2 | Child-3 | **Parent-2** | Child-4 | Child-5 | **Parent-3** | Child-6

How do you achieve this in CSS or alternatively with the help of jquery? Seems like a simple thing but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you ever heard of `float` or `inline-block`?

Comment: Thats why he/she posted this question, I guess...

Comment: I think the question is part float vs. inline-block but the OP also needs guidance adding the "|" characters programatically. (my answer below provides solutions to both problems as pure CSS.

Comment: I tried both float and inline-block but didn't get it to work. The trick was to use inline-block on both ul and li as seen below from drew_w's answer. I only tried it on li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this isn't maybe exactly what you want but it should get you started. Apply the following css to your li/ul:

```
ul, li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you want to see this working check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cvf33/

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my problem. I didn't put inline-block on the ul element, hence I didn't get it to work.

Comment: @user3446283 If this fixed your issue - feel free to mark as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is very easily done by using the `display: inline-block;` property and value.  The inline-block property tells the element to behave like a paragraph, lining up from left to right on a single line until there is no more width available.  At that point it line breaks to a second line.

The effect is achieved by telling the UL elements to be `inline-block`, which aligns all of the UL's next to each other.  Then by applying the same `inline-block` to the LI elements aligns those left to right inside the UL's.  You can see the different results by commenting out the `display: inline-block;` line in each of the two selectors below.

Inline-block is IE8 and forward compatible.  See this [Can I Use It](http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block) link for details on compatibility.

*Note that the extra CSS (height and background) is just for visual demonstration and are not integral to the function of the code*

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3e5W/)

```
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
}

ul li { 
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
}

ul li ul.sub-menu li {
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
ul, li {display: inline-block;}
ul, li {margin:0; padding: 0; text-align: left;}
li + li::before {
    content: " | ";
}
ul::before {
    content: " | ";
}
.container::before {
    content: " ";
}
ul li {font-weight: bold;}
ul li ul li {font-weight: normal;}
</style>

<ul class="container">
 <li>Parent-1
  <ul>
    <li>Child-1</li>
    <li>Child-2</li>
    <li>Child-3</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Parent-2
  <ul>
    <li>Child-4</li>
    <li>Child-5</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Parent-3
  <ul>
    <li>Child-6</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Note that I gave the outer-most ul a class name of "container" in order to remove the leading "|"